# Elastic Search get items in array filed that all meet to requirements?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm really new to Elastic Search, and now blocked by one problem.

If I use GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/type/_search, the result is

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "AVe3AcpYbUIbMIPUYcZ2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "applications": [
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "country": "a"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "country": "b"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 3,
                  "country": "c"
                },
                {
                  "id": 4,
                  "country": "d"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "AVe3cMaPbUIbMIPUYcaS",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "applications": [
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "country": "aa"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 33,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 44,
                  "country": "aa"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "AVe3b1KmbUIbMIPUYcaR",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "applications": [
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "country": "bb"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 33,
                  "country": "cc"
                },
                {
                  "id": 44,
                  "country": "d"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what I want is to get one application that every job.country in the application is "aa", so the expected result is

```
"applications": [
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "country": "aa"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 33,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 44,
                  "country": "aa"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
```

What I have tried is POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/type/_search

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "applications.jobs.country": "aa"
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is

```
{
  "took": 65,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.30685282,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "AVe3cMaPbUIbMIPUYcaS",
        "_score": 0.30685282,
        "_source": {
          "applications": [
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "country": "aa"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 33,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 44,
                  "country": "aa"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "AVe3b1KmbUIbMIPUYcaR",
        "_score": 0.15342641,
        "_source": {
          "applications": [
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "country": "aa"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "country": "bb"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "jobs": [
                {
                  "id": 33,
                  "country": "cc"
                },
                {
                  "id": 44,
                  "country": "d"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems that if application contains a applications.jobs.country meet to the requirements ,it will be returned. and I want to get those every item in applications.jobs meets to need. anybody can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use to regex to solve this problem temporarily.
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/type/_search

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "regexp": {
                    "applications.jobs.country": "~(.*aa.*)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

must not contains that applications.jobs.country contains other than "aa"